# Serializing an abstract list in Protobuf-net

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

I have the following class structure in my application:

```
[ProtoContract]
public abstract class WebSyncedObject
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public DateTime SystemTime { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public bool TimeSynchronized { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public ulong RelativeTime { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(4)]
    public Guid BootID { get; set; }

    protected WebSyncedObject()
    {
        BootID = BootID.GetBootID();
        if (BootID == Guid.Empty) return;

        TimeSynchronized = Time.TimeSynchronized;
        RelativeTime = Time.RelativeTime;
        SystemTime = DateTime.Now;
    }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class GPSReading : WebSyncedObject
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public DateTime SatelliteTime { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public decimal Latitude { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public decimal Longitude { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(4)]
    public int NumSatellites { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(5)]
    public decimal SpeedKM { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class TemperatureReading : WebSyncedObject
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public decimal Temperature { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public int NodeID { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public string ProbeIdentifier { get; set; }
}
```

I then construct a List<WebSynchedObject> with data of both types, and try to serialize with Protobuf-net when I get the following exception:

> InvalidOperationException
>   Unexpected sub-type: Logger.TemperatureReading

I've read about the ProtoInclude attribute, but I don't want to use that as my code needs to be easily extendable, and I'm not sure on how the numbering on the RuntimeTypeModel approach is supposed to work, since I've also seen warnings about generating that automagically.

Is there any way to achieve this whilst making it extendable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, there needs to be a robust, reliable and repeatable way of the library identifying a specific sub-type (`GPSReading`, etc) with a unique identifier (a field-number). In many cases, the most *convenient* way to do that is via attributes. However, if this is not an option, you can also do this at runtime - perhaps reading the identifiers some configuration file. It would not be a good idea to just say (at runtime) "find all the available sub-types, order them alphabetically, and increment them starting at (say) 10", because in a later build you might have added an `AltitudeReading`, which would change the number of *everything*, breaking the existing data. But as long as you can define these in a *repeatable manner*, then all is good. For example, with attributes...

```
[ProtoInclude(10, typeof(GPSReading))]
[ProtoInclude(11, typeof(TemperatureReading))]
[ProtoInclude(12, typeof(AltitudeReading))]
```

But you could also do something in a text file, or an xml configuration file... maybe:

```
<add key="10" type="Some.Namespace.GPSReading"/>
<add key="11" type="Some.Namespace.TemperatureReading"/>
<add key="12" type="Some.Namespace.AltitudeReading"/>
```

and add you own code that reads the config file, and calls:

```
int key = int.Parse(element.GetAttributeValue("key"));
Type type = someAssembly.GetType(element.GetAttributeValue("type"));
RuntimeTypeModel.Default[typeof(WebSyncedObject)].AddSubType(key, type);
```

Again, to emphasize: the important thing is that the numbers associated with each sub-type *must be robustly repeatable in the future*. As long as you can guarantee that, it is not required to use attributes. But the model *does need to know* the identifiers.

Comment: I've temporarily hardcoded: RuntimeTypeModel.Default[typeof(WebSyncedObject)].AddSubType(10, typeof(GPSReading)); and the same for TemperatureReading with a key of 11. However now even if I try to deserialize a single object using Serializer.Deserialize<GPSReading>(ms); I get "No parameterless constructor found for WebSynchedObject".

Comment: @PeterBelm was the inheritance relationship part of the model when you serialized?

Comment: updating the RuntimeTypeModel is the first thing I do in Main(). Could this be an issue going across assemblies? The code that does the deserialization is done in a referenced DLL. Doing the deserialization in Main() just after updating the RuntimeTypeModel works fine but I can't keep it like that.

Comment: @PeterBelm sorry, I can't quite understand what you are saying there. Across assemblies shouldn't make any difference; across *app-domains* would require configuration in each. But again - I'm struggling to understand what you said there - can you rephrase?

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to balance getting this into my final app and recreating it in a simple test case. Here's my test case which works: http://pastebin.com/ek5tyrfk the classes WebSynchedObject, GPSReading, and TemperatureReading are defined in a referenced DLL. However if I try to take this over to my actual app like this pseudo code: http://pastebin.com/XgWY4XLV I get the "No parameterless constructor found for WebSynchedObject". Hopefully that was more understandable.

Comment: Ah nevermind, it was my fault. The program I have that takes and serializes the readings didn't have the RuntimeTypeModel set up. Now it does and everything works fine.

Comment: @PeterBelm you don't need to use MakeGenericMethod, btw - either use RuntimeTypeModel.Default.[De]Serialize, or Serializer.NonGeneric.[De]Serialize - and you can pass the `Type` in as an instance.